# Power BI - R Script Visual - Apriori

Tags: r, powerbi, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I'm using an r script visual in PowerBI. I can run the below code in R and it works, but I get the error below when running in PowerBI. I want to show the results from apriori in a visual. Both tests below run fine in R, but NOT in R script visual from PowerBI. Any thoughts?

if I try #test2.

```
library(Matrix)
library(arules)
library(plyr)
library(gridExtra)

df_itemList <- ddply(dataset,c("SALESID"),function(df1)paste(df1$ITEMID))
#test1
#df_itemList  = sapply(df_itemList , function(x) gsub(" ", ",", x))
#basket_rules <- apriori(df_itemList, parameter = list(sup=0.1,conf=0.5,target="rules", maxlen=5));

#test2
txn = read.transactions(df_itemList, rm.duplicates = TRUE, format = "basket", sep = ",", cols = 1);
basket_rules <- apriori(txn, parameter = list(sup=0.1,conf=0.5,target="rules", maxlen=5));

df_basket <- as(basket_rules,"data.frame")
grid.table(df_basket)
```

Error Message:
R script error.

Attaching package: 'arules'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

```
abbreviate, write
```

Error in readLines(file, encoding = encoding) : 'con' is not a connection
Calls: read.transactions -> lapply -> readLines
Execution halted

If I try #test1...

```
library(Matrix)
library(arules)
library(plyr)
library(gridExtra)

df_itemList <- ddply(dataset,c("SALESID"),function(df1)paste(df1$ITEMID))
#test1
df_itemList  = sapply(df_itemList , function(x) gsub(" ", ",", x))
basket_rules <- apriori(df_itemList, parameter = list(sup=0.1,conf=0.5,target="rules", maxlen=5));

#test2
#txn = read.transactions(df_itemList, rm.duplicates = TRUE, format = "basket", sep = ",", cols = 1);
#basket_rules <- apriori(txn, parameter = list(sup=0.1,conf=0.5,target="rules", maxlen=5));

df_basket <- as(basket_rules,"data.frame")
grid.table(df_basket)
```

Then I get the error below.

Error Message:
R script error.

Attaching package: 'arules'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

```
abbreviate, write
```

Error in asMethod(object) : 
  column(s) 2, 3, 4 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
Calls: apriori -> as -> asMethod
Execution halted

Comment: The `read.transactions` call in the code you posted is commented out, yet your error message contains that call. Is the commented out code part of what you ran? If so, the error is unrelated to R vs PowerBI and simply due to the fact that you didn’t pass a filename to the `read.transactions` call but a dataframe.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was running 2 tests... I updated my original post.

Comment: I'm expecting to deploy this report to Powerbi service... Am I not able to use apriori without calling a file? Can't I just use a dataset?

Comment: I urge you to [read the arules vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/vignettes/arules.pdf), which explains how to call `apriori` correctly, and, in particular, how to construct a “transactions” object that can be passed to the `apriori` function (section 5.2; although you can also pass the data frame directly).  — Anyway, this really has nothing to do with R vs Power BI.

Comment: I'll take a look. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to use read.transactions in a PowerBI R script is to convert the dataframe to a matrix, then to the transactions class. This is to by pass the exporting to a csv, then read back in to read.transactions... Reference [here](http://www.learnbymarketing.com/1043/working-with-arules-transactions-and-read-transactions/)

```
library(Matrix)
library(arules)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

itemList <- dataset
#itemList <- read.csv("ItemListAll.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

# Converting to a Matrix ####
itemList$const = TRUE

# Remove duplicates
dim(itemList)
orders <- unique(itemList)
dim(itemList)

# Need to reshape the matrix
itemList_max_prep <- reshape(data = itemList,
                           idvar = "SALESID",
                           timevar = "ITEMID",
                           direction = "wide")

# Drop the SALESID
itemList_matrix <- as.matrix(itemList_max_prep[,-1])

# Clean up the missing values to be FALSE
itemList_matrix[is.na(itemList_matrix)] <- FALSE

# Clean up names
colnames(itemList_matrix) <- gsub(x=colnames(itemList_matrix),
                               pattern="const\\.", replacement="")

itemList_trans <- as(itemList_matrix,"transactions")

#inspect(itemList_trans)

basket_rules <- apriori(itemList_trans, parameter = list(sup=0.01,conf=0.5,target="rules", minlen=3));
df_basket <- as(basket_rules,"data.frame")
df_basket$support <- ceiling(df_basket$support * 100)
df_basket$confidence<- ceiling(df_basket$confidence * 100)
df_basket$lift<- round(df_basket$lift, digits = 2)
df_basket <- df_basket[rev(order(df_basket$support)),];
grid.table(head(df_basket));
```